# Debug and executing QT project with cmake and CLion

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, clion

I try run QT project with cmake and CLion. On my Windows 10 I have installed MinGw and QT. I got folder source with this files:

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>435</width>
    <height>308</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>124</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>151</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>My Button :)</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

My code structure is very common, the same that in start project in QT creator. Now I have my CmakeList file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(MyProject)

set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\5.5\\mingw492_32")
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(Qt5Widgets)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

add_library(mainwindow sources/mainwindow.cpp)
target_link_libraries (mainwindow Qt5::Widgets)

add_executable(qtProject sources/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(qtProject Qt5::Widgets mainwindow)
```

Cmake fetch cmakelist without errors and warning. Next compilation going also without errors. When I finally run program window not show up. I see only that app return this code: -1073741515 (0xC0000135). Why QT didnt open window ? Second thing, when I set in CLion in some place breakpoint and I run debug mode CLion didnt stop in my brakepoint, this looks like current lib didnt have debug symbols, how to easiest add debug version of qt library ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try copying all the .dll that you find in C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin into your executable folder (you can see it befor -1073741515 (0xC0000135): is something like C:\Users{yourName}.CLion2016.2\system\cmake\generated{nameproject}-34b1f222\34b1f222\Debug
Then run your project from Clion. If it shows you a window you can select the dlls that you have copied and (while the exe is running) try to delete them: the system will hold only ones it needs. I did so when I used QT for the first time. 
Then i changed my CMake and now it works without dlls in the executable folder.
I use MinGw downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Timer_Scandiffio)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp MyClock.cpp MyClock.h
        TimerDisplay.cpp TimerDisplay.h MyTimerApp.h
        MyTimerApp.cpp MyTimerApp.ui )

add_executable(Timer_Scandiffio ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(QT5 NEED)
find_package( Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package( Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package( Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package( Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(Timer_Scandiffio Qt5::Core)
target_link_libraries(Timer_Scandiffio Qt5::Gui)
target_link_libraries(Timer_Scandiffio Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(Timer_Scandiffio Qt5::Multimedia)
```